# Convert date String to readable date

Tags: swift, timestamp

I get a date from sever like that: `"2020-07-20T23:03:11.17926"`
I think to make it readable, I have to convert it to timestamp, then convert it to a readable string again.

Here is my code:

```
func timeStringFromUnixTime(timestamp: String) -> String {
  let stringDate = timestamp
  let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
  dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
  let dateString = dateFormatter.date(from: stringDate)
  
  //get timestamp from Date
  if let dateTimeStamp  = dateString?.timeIntervalSince1970 {
     let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval(dateTimeStamp))
     dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM d, h:mm"
     dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: NSTimeZone.default.identifier)
     let localDate = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
     return localDate
  }
  return ""
}
```

But the problem is, `dateString` will be equal to `nil`, so it returns a empty string. Could anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
```

with:

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"
```

- `Z` - "RFC 822 GMT format. Can also match a literal Z for Zulu (UTC) time."
- `SSS` - "The milliseconds."

Take a look at [NSDateFormatter.com](https://nsdateformatter.com) to see more about date formatting.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help :)

Comment: There is many issues on OP code that should be addressed. 1) DateFormatter locale should be set to "en_US_POSIX" otherwise it might fail if run a device with 24h time settings turned off.  2) dateString it is not a string it is an optional date. Converting it to seconds and back to date is pointless. 3) "MMM d, h:mm" date format it is missing the AM/PM. 4) Setting the timezone to current it is not needed since it is the default. Btw `TimeZone(identifier: NSTimeZone.default.identifier)` is definitely awkward why not simply `.current` but in this case OP can just remove the whole line of code.